# Col leads to same default value in columns with similar className

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

When I try the following:

```
  <Col sm={12} lg={5} className="highlighted-card d-grid mt-4 mt-lg-0">
    <h3 className="mb-4">Stat</h3>
    <p>
      Buy on this
    </p>
    <Form.Control type="number" aria-label="number input" DefaultValue="20"
                  className="percent mt-auto"/>
  </Col>
```

And another Col:

```
  <Col sm={12} lg={5} className="highlighted-card d-grid mt-4 mt-lg-0">
    <h3 className="mb-4">Max Stat</h3>
    <p className="">
      Total
    </p>
    <Form.Control type="number" aria-label="number input" defaultValue="17" className="mt-auto"/>
  </Col>
```

The default value always stays the same. Example in the above code it is always 20.

I tried setting different `id=`, `Value` instead of `DefaultValue`, etc. But doesn't work.

If I remove `<Col></Col>` then the values can be set differently.

What is the issue here?